# Show that the tangent bundle is locally a product,i.e., $TU=U\times\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Show that the tangent bundle is locally a product,i.e., $TU=U\times\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Where $TM$ is the set of pairs $(q,v),q\in M,v\in T_{q}M$, if $(U,x)$ is a coordinate system in $M$, then all vector of $T_{q}M,q\in x(U)$ is write as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{y_{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}}$, I don't see why tangent bundle is locally a product, perhaps I can find a isomorphism between two spaces of locally way, thanks!